# Force balance with different points from centre of rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]
Problem is as shown in the image above.

The shape made of **black lines** is a **rigid body**. The input force of 100N is exerted on **point 1**; this causes torque of 100N.m at the rotation point.

What is the force balance of this example? What is N2 and N3?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Can you state the problem as a complete question or sentence?

Comment: Its not copied from a book or anything. This is my own question. Ill try to explain it clearer to you.

Comment: The whole shape made from “black” lines is a rigid body. You apply 100N at the beginning of this rigid body, where its creating a torque at the point of rotation. Now, how does it translate in terms of force on the other two points?

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarity.  So you are not trying to "balance" torques with the ?, you want to know how the applied torque accelerated those other points.  This would be due to the constraint imposed that the body is rigid.  There is no external force applied to those points.  But there is an internal force from the "elements" of mass connected to it.  While accelerating the internal forces clearly do not balance on a single element and this is experienced as stress in the rods.

Comment: But I guess you want to know the value of that stress.

Comment: Sorry, I made it really confusing, but "Balance" is the word I was looking for. So basically what is the force balance on this rigid body (arrows should on the "?N" points)?

Comment: Okay, so you do want to choose the applied forces so that angular acceleration = 0, either uniform rotation or statics.  I'd start by setting up Newton's second law as a vector equation and the torque equation then see if you have enough equations to solve for the unknowns.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Are the 2 N forces meant to be equal in magnitude?

Comment: No. The "?N" forces are not meant to be equal. So from the balance equation:

Comment: 100N.m = 0.5m * N1 + 0.75m * N2, right? How do I find n1 and n2?

Comment: Ah, you didn't have N1 and N2 in the pic.  You also need to balance the forces since the CoM is not moving.  And for that there is the force of the joint at point of rotation.  It may be an under specified problem.  That is there may be a set of possible solutions based on the equations.  Like finding N for each leg of a table, usually 1/4 the weight (1/number_of_legs).  Can you argue that if 2 pts are in contact that the reaction force but be evenly distributed?  Look up the table problem as see how that is approached.

Comment: I feel like this should still have the homework tag, even though the OP claims it's not his homework.

Comment: Why should I add "homework" tag?

Comment: Thank you ggcg, ill look it up. I think you are right, after having a closer look, it looks like there are infinite amount of solutions to this problem.

Comment: It might be that Im looking at it from a wrong perspective. Basically I was trying to work out a force distribution on a spring system. So basically point 2 and 3 would be rubber bushings of the same stiffness (assuming linear stiffness).